# Command 'Syso(Ctrl + " space")' not working in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse IDE (version Juno) fails to show System.out.println() when I enter Syso(Ctrl + ‘Space’) according to rule. How to fix it? Why is this erratic behavior taking place? Let me inform, it doesn’t happen all the time but yes sometimes it does occur! My OS is Windows 8, 64-bit system.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on an [Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/?)

Comment: In my case eclipse proposes "sysout" in the completion box when I enter "sys<ctrl+space>" and when I enter "sysout<ctrl+space>" it expands it with no asking.

Comment: BTW: asking programming IDE questions are on-topic on StackOverflow. `if your question generally covers…software tools commonly used by programmers`.

Answer (score 2):

You can go one step further and get Code assist in eclipse.

1. Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist
2. Auto Activation > Auto activation triggers for Java
3. Enter all the characters you want to trigger autocomplete, such as the following:

   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._

Comment: Right after doing what both of you have suggested(#Zeus and #Dazak), it’s coming as: when I write Syso in Eclipse IDE, and then press ‘Ctrl + Space’ then it shows the list of Template proposals as sysout. When I select this ‘sysout’ it prints System.out.println(“”); on screen. But my question is: just a few days ago, there was no such problem with Syso, it was working fine. Why and how did this sudden change take place?

Answer (score 0):

Try just writing syso (lower case) and then push ctrl+space. If is still not working, then verify that you have selected the template...

Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates

[image: Template select]

Also verify that in the right side the column `Auto Insert` is `on`

Comment: Right after doing what both of you have suggested(#Zeus and #Dazak), it’s coming as: when I write Syso in Eclipse IDE, and then press ‘Ctrl + Space’ then it shows the list of Template proposals as sysout. When I select this ‘sysout’ it prints System.out.println(“”); on screen. But my question is: just a few days ago, there was no such problem with Syso, it was working fine. Why and how did this sudden change take place?